# Find how a point divides the sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry

Given a triangle $AB$C. On the sides $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$ points $A_1$, $B_1$ and $C_1$ have been selected respectively. Medians $A_1A_2$, $B_1B_2$ and $C_1C_2$ of the triangle $A_1B_1C_1$ are parallel to $AB$, $BC$ and $CA$ respectively. How can I find in what relationship do points $A_1$, $B_1$ and $C_1$ divide the sides of the triangle $ABC$[image]?

Comment: Your diagram is not very accurate, $A_1 A_2$ is quite far from being parallel to $AB$.

Comment: Additionally, what are your attempts? This problem is straightforward to solve through barycentric coordinates, for instance.

Comment: You may also assume that $ABC$ is equilateral without loss of generality, since affine maps preserve midpoints and parallel lines.

Comment: Let O be an intersection point of the medians. I continued the medians until their intersection with AC, AB and BC in the points P, Q and R respectively. We can prove that OA2 is the middle line of the triangle B1C1Q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since affine maps preserve midpoints and parallel lines we may assume without loss of generality that $ABC$ is equilateral. The following configuration trivially fulfills the wanted constraints

[image]

hence $A_1,B_1,C_1$ all lie at two thirds of the corresponding side.

Comment: Nice affine solution!   +1